# Getting the position of a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function perso_div_add_text (id) {
      $('#perso_div').append('<span class="dragables off-focus" onmousedown="moused('+id+');" id="dragables_t'+id+'" contenteditable="true"></span>');
    }
$('#btn-add-text').on('click',function(){
    var s=$('#perso_div').find("span");
    if(s.length>0){
        if(confirm("you have already added text, want to add more??")){
            perso_div_add_text((s.length)+1);
        }
    }else{
        perso_div_add_text((s.length)+1);
    }
});
```

I am creating elements dynamically in a div, these all functions mentioned are working fine, but not this one

```
function moused (id) {
  console.log('#dragables_t'+id);
    console.log($('#dragables_t'+id).pageX+','+$('#dragables_t'+id).pageY);
//
}
```

I tried pageXOffset/pageYOffset, screenX/screenY all of them returned undefined. help please

Comment: did you call `moused()` on `document.ready` ?

Comment: when `document.ready` runs that element is not present, and the function is not inside `document.ready` function, and its running but returning `undefined,undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position` jQuery Api

Try this code:

```
    function moused (id) { 
         console.log('#dragables_t'+id); 
         console.log($('#dragables_t'+id).position().left+'
                   ,'+$('#dragables_t'+id).position().top);
    }
```

check out [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#dragables_t'+id).offset().left` and `$('#dragables_t'+id).offset().top`

See [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

About pageX ,you have to know this property comes from jQuery event object,neither jQuery object nor dom object has this property.

In order to use pageX,you have to bind your event like this:

```
$("body").on("mousedown",".dragables off-focus",function(event){
    console.log(event.pageX+','+event.pageY);
})
```

And don't forget to remove code `onmousedown="moused('+id+');"`.

If you are trying to get the position from its parent,you should use jQuery position:

`$('#dragables_t'+id).position().left` and `$('#dragables_t'+id).position().top`

See [jQuery position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: yeah cool, but its giving left and top from the body, how can i get the position from its parent

Comment: see my update,but I'm confused,`offset().left` is getting the position from body,`pageX` is getting mouse position from body,`position().left` is getting the position from its parent,what are you want?

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**

```
onmousedown="moused('+id+');"
```

which ultimately turns to something like `moused(dragables_t5)`

**to this**

```
onmousedown="moused(\''+id+'\');"
```

which ultimately turns to something like `moused('dragables_t5')`